# Cube rendering as Sphere

Tags: rendering

This is happening on multiple projects now... I create a cube, assign materials and when I click on render > render image it shows all cubes as spheres instead. This happens with both Cycles render and Blender render.

[image: Unrendered]
[image: Rendered]

I am very new to blender. Is there something I am doing that would cause this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What you didn't include in the images in your question is the subsurf modifier you are using.

Comment: @MrZak - That is exactly what was happening.... Like I said, complete newbie here..... Thanks!